# Finding numbers within a certain range in an arraylist

Tags: java, netbeans, methods, arraylist, range

I have an Integer array list that collects numbers that the user inputs. I have to display numbers within the array that <= 50, using a method. How can I do this?

```
public static double levelR(List<Integer> marks){
  for (int i= marks.get(0); i<= 50; i++){
      System.println(marks.get(i));  
}
```

This is all I have for the method so far, I'm clueless on what to do next.

Comment: for (int n : marks) if (n<=50) System.out.println(n);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to sort the array to solve this problem. Here is what you do:

- Start by writing a loop that prints all elements of the array regardless of the value
- Modify your loop to skip printing numbers above 50. There are two ways of doing this - adding an `if` that uses `continue` on numbers above 50, or add an `if` around printing.

Comment: sorry but im kinda new, how would i do this? I know how to make loops but im not really sure what you mean by printing elements

Comment: @NafimTalukder Could you edit the question to add a loop instead of sorting? You would need to use something like `System.out.println()` with the value that you are printing.

Comment: I edited it with that, but just to let you know once i get the number of elements < 50, i have to put it in a ratio to all the number of elements in the array. Like 4:8, for example.

Comment: @NafimTalukder - If this answer has answered your question, please accept it.  The rest of your homework is for >>you<< to do.

Comment: @NafimTalukder That is not the right loop: it would not print all numbers. `i` needs to iterate from zero to `marks.length`.

Answer (score 0):

It takes one line in Java 8:

```
// Given: List<Integer> marks;
marks.stream().filter(x -> x <= 50).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sample just print the value from the list which <=50

```
public class ArrayListDemo {
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(10);
    list.add(60);
    list.add(70);
    list.add(30);
    list.add(40);
    list.add(50);

    System.out.println(list);

    for (Integer singleValue: list) {
        if(singleValue<=50) 
            System.out.println(singleValue);
    }
}
```

}

Output:
[10, 60, 70, 30, 40, 50] 
10 
30 
40 
50

You can also create a new list and on the basis of the your condition store in it.